# Different Constraints for Different Size Classes

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, size-classes

Is it possible to have different constraints/views for different size classes in Xcode? I am trying to constraint from an inferred view but it messes up the views for different size classes so is it possible just to make a different view for each size class?

Answer (score 0):

Constraints, yes. That's the entire point of size classes. You should probably read through [apple's docs on the matter.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) As far as I know there isn't a built in way to truly have different views per se, but you can can choose to show/hide views in different sizes. Regardless, Apple would recommend you use a nib/storyboard and work with all sizes/devices using the same storyboard/nibs and classes.